# iOS wireless ad hoc distribution fails at the end of download with "Unable to download..." message

Tags: ios, distribution, wireless, adhoc

iOS wireless ad hoc distribution fails at the end of download with "Unable to download..." message. I followed steps in the answer of here: [iOS 4: wireless app distribution for in-house applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3098290/ios-4-wireless-app-distribution-for-in-house-applications) .

Any workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got solution. I did not downloaded `Provisioning Profile`.
A new device should download proper `Provisioning Profile` before downloading the app.

Comment: I have the same problem, but mine still doesn't work after installing the profile. Do you have to add the device ID to the profile somewhere first?

Comment: @Davido Yes, you have to add the device's UDID to the Ad Hoc profile at the dev portal and then download a new version.

Comment: I actually figured it out. I got it working so I don't have to have a specific list of UDID values in the profile. A link can be emailed to anyone and they can install it from the shortcut to a server.

Comment: @Davido How did you accomplish that?

Comment: see my post here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5546581/how-to-distribute-ios-application-wirelessly-without-managing-udids-and-recompila/5558057#5558057