# Copy Folder from main bundle to documents directory in iphone

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I am having an app in which I have a folder named "Images" in my main bundle.

In This folder there is another folder called "Images1" containing some images.

When my app Launch I want the folder "Images" on the documents directory.

I want to fetch images from the folder "Images1".

But I can't get my images in the folder "Images" at documents directory with the following code.

**Edited**

```
       BOOL success1;
    NSFileManager *fileManager1 = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSError *error1;
    NSArray *paths1 = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory1 = [paths1 objectAtIndex:0];
   NSString *writableDBPath1 = [documentsDirectory1 stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Images/Images1"];
    success1 = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:writableDBPath1];

    if (success1) return;
    // The writable database does not exist, so copy the default to the appropriate location.
    NSString *defaultDBPath1 = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Images/Images1"];

    NSLog(@"Default : %@",defaultDBPath1);
    success1 = [fileManager1 copyItemAtPath:defaultDBPath1 toPath:writableDBPath1 error:&error1];

    if (!success1) {
        NSAssert1(0, @"Failed to create writable database file with message '%@'.", [error1 localizedDescription]);

    }
```

Please help me.

Comment: as a side note: prepare for app store rejection because you most likely violate the [data storage guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/PerformanceTuning/PerformanceTuning.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH8-SW9). You are not supposed to save data you can easily recreate in the documents directory.

Answer (score 4):

Are you sure that you have the files in your folder tree?

```
NSString *defaultDBPath1 = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/Images/Images1"];
```

usually when xcode make a package it flatten the directory contents. So first check you have all the things in your source folder. Even if you see that the folder is shown in your package explorer, when copied in the app, you will see the images are in the root folder. To avoid this, when you add the Image folder, in your xcode project, you can check the option to 'create folder reference'.

However, your write may fail because of an overwrite. In that case you have to implement a delegate method for `NSFileManager` given below.

```
- (void) copyFolder {
    BOOL success1;
    NSFileManager *fileManager1 = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    fileManager1.delegate = self;
    NSError *error1;
    NSArray *paths1 = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory1 = [paths1 objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *writableDBPath1 = [documentsDirectory1 stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/Images"];
    success1 = [fileManager1 fileExistsAtPath:writableDBPath1];
    if (success1 )
    {

        NSString *defaultDBPath1 = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Images"];
        NSLog(@"default path %@",defaultDBPath1);
        success1 = [fileManager1 copyItemAtPath:defaultDBPath1 toPath:writableDBPath1 error:&error1];
    } else {
        if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:writableDBPath1])
            [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:writableDBPath1 withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:&error1];
    }
}

- (BOOL)fileManager:(NSFileManager *)fileManager shouldProceedAfterError:(NSError *)error copyingItemAtPath:(NSString *)srcPath toPath:(NSString *)dstPath{
    if ([error code] == 516) //error code for: The operation couldn’t be completed. File exists
        return YES;
    else
        return NO;
}
```

Comment: Yes, I do have. I can't understand what is wrong in this code. Please help if u know.

Comment: I think this is the key: createDirectoryAtPath:.  The directory doesn't exist in your docs folder and iOS file manager won't make directories automatically for you.  You need to explicitly create them.