# Can't copy Folder's contents from app bundle to document directory

Tags: objective-c, ios8, nsfilemanager

here i referred this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17669944/copy-folder-from-main-bundle-to-documents-directory-in-iphone) to copy folders from app bundle to document directory.Folders created successfully but not it's contents.I write this code to my `"AppDeleget.m"`. I want to copy main folder with subdirectories.

```
- (void) copyFolder {
    BOOL success1;
    NSFileManager *fileManager1 = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    fileManager1.delegate = self;
    NSError *error1;
    NSArray *paths1 = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory1 = [paths1 objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *writableDBPath1 = [documentsDirectory1 stringByAppendingPathComponent:mainFolder];
    success1 = [fileManager1 fileExistsAtPath:writableDBPath1];
    if (success1 )
    {
        NSString *defaultDBPath1 = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:mainFolder];
        NSLog(@"\ndefault path %@",defaultDBPath1);
        success1 = [fileManager1 copyItemAtPath:defaultDBPath1 toPath:writableDBPath1 error:&error1];
        NSLog(@"\n#Error:-\n%@",error1.localizedDescription);
    }
    else {
        if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:writableDBPath1])
            [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:writableDBPath1 withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:&error1];
    }
    NSLog(@"\nWritableDB path %@",writableDBPath1);
}

- (BOOL)fileManager:(NSFileManager *)fileManager shouldProceedAfterError:(NSError *)error copyingItemAtPath:(NSString *)srcPath toPath:(NSString *)dstPath{
    if ([error code] == 516) //error code for: The operation couldn’t be completed. File exists
        return YES;
    else
        return NO;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer..!,the issue was i want copy a folder from app bundle to my app's document directory.so,first manually create folder named `temp` than i put my contents in `temp` folder which i want in my app than i renamed `temp` folder to `temp.bundle` this will ask confirmation from user. just give ok. than i use the bellow code in my `AppDelegate.m` to make thing possible.

```
- (void) copyFolder {
    BOOL success1;
    NSFileManager *fileManager1 = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    fileManager1.delegate = self;
    NSError *error1;
    NSArray *paths1 = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory1 = [paths1 objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *writableDBPath1 = [documentsDirectory1 stringByAppendingPathComponent:mainFolder];
    success1 = [fileManager1 fileExistsAtPath:writableDBPath1];
    if (!success1 )
    {
        NSLog(@"IN");
        NSString *bundlePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"temp" ofType:@"bundle"];
        NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:bundlePath];
        NSString *path = [bundle resourcePath];
        //NSLog(@"\nPath:-\n%@",path);
        NSFileManager *fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
        NSError *error = [[NSError alloc] init];
        NSArray *directoryAndFileNames = [fm contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:path error:&error];
        //NSLog(@"\ndirectoryAndFileName:-\n%@",directoryAndFileNames);
        NSString* from=[NSString new];
        from=[path stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[directoryAndFileNames firstObject]]];
        success1=[[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:from toPath:writableDBPath1 error:&error1];
        if(success1){
            NSLog(@"Done");
        }
        else{
            NSLog(@"NOT Done");
        }
    }
}
```

this code will work once to get your folders with contents to your app's document directory.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to copy a directory/folder and all it's contents then you need a recursive copy method. This is where you cycle through a directory's contents and sub contents ad infinitum until all have been copied. Thusly:

```
- (BOOL)recursiveCopyFilesAtPath:(NSString *)origin toPath:(NSString *)destination
{
    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:origin]) {
        if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:destination]) {
            NSError *error1 = nil;
            if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:destination withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:&error1]) {
                NSLog(@"Failed to create directory at path: %@. Error: %@.", destination, error1.localizedDescription);
                return NO;
            }
        }
        // Recursive copy
        [self copyContentsOfDirectory:origin toPath:destination];
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"No files at path: %@", origin);
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}

- (void)copyContentsOfDirectory:(NSString *)dir toPath:(NSString *)path
{
    for (NSString *file in [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:dir error:nil]) {
        NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[dir stringByAppendingPathComponent:file]];
        NSNumber *isDirectory = nil;
        if (![url getResourceValue:&isDirectory forKey:NSURLIsDirectoryKey error:nil]) {
            NSLog(@"Failed to get resource value for item at path: %@", [dir stringByAppendingPathComponent:file]);
        }
        else {
            if (isDirectory.boolValue) {
                // Create equivalent directory at new path...
                NSError *erro = nil;
                if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:[path stringByAppendingPathComponent:file] withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:&erro]) {
                    NSLog(@"Failed to create directory at path: %@. Error: %@", [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:file], erro.localizedDescription);
                }
                // This is where the process loops until there are no subdirectories left...
                [self copyContentsOfDirectory:[dir stringByAppendingPathComponent:file] toPath:[path stringByAppendingPathComponent:file]];
            }
            else {
                NSError *err = nil;
                if (![self copyFileFromPath:[dir stringByAppendingPathComponent:file] toPath:path error:err]) {
                    NSLog(@"Failed to copy item at path: %@. Error: %@", [dir stringByAppendingPathComponent:path], err.localizedDescription);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

- (BOOL)copyFileFromPath:(NSString *)path toPath:(NSString *)dest error:(NSError *)error
{
    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:path]) {
        return [[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:path toPath:[dest stringByAppendingPathComponent:dest.lastPathComponent] error:&error];
    }
    return NO;
}
```

Note: This is untested code that I'm just using to give you the idea.

Also note that this is potentially a lengthy task that should not be performed on the main thread and should be called like this...

```
// Prep UI
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
     if (![self recursiveCopyFilesAtPath:origin toPath:destination]) {
            NSLog(@"Failed to copy files at path: %@", origin);
     }
     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        // Update UI and notify user...
    });
});
```