# In-house app won't work after 1 year

Tags: ipad, provisioning-profile, ipa

I created in-house app for iPad and we'll use that app in around 100 iPads.
From research I got info that After expired registration created provisioning-profile won't work and because of that APP won't work too.

IS it true?

What can be the solution?

Comment: Please post links to your research. Are you getting an error message?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8136307/enterprise-in-house-app-distribution

Comment: It appears that every year you will have to push the app with the new certificate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it true?

Yes, but only for apps built for enterprise distribution. (Probably ad hoc, too, but those may expire sooner.)

> What can be the solution?

Update the app with a new distribution provision.

Comment: Just go to the developer portal, get a new provision profile, and rebuild the app. If you had known about this earlier, you might also have designed the current version to check for newer versions and suggest that the user download a new copy.