# Make an app downloadable form a safari webpage

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, web-applications, safari

So I want to make a soundboard app that me and a few friends can use. I want it to be so that when they go to my free website on their iphone they can click on install on the top of the screen and install the IPA file. How do I do this? I know how to make the app btw :P

Comment: The first thing, you can do it with some points keeping in mind. You have to go for Enterprise developer account. You have to upload your IPA on a repository. Only limited allowed users can install your app. Look on these links
1. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8136307/enterprise-in-house-app-distribution
2. https://github.com/nifcblm/AHPP-iOS-App/wiki/How-to-distribute-enterprise-iOS-App

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is you can't. The closest you'll get is using TestFlight/hockey to deploy beta builds but you'll need to collect device UUIDs and provision the app to be installable on the target audience's devices. Any time you want to add a device you'll need to create a new provisioning profile and rebuild the app.

Comment: But is there no way I can send my friends the app without them going to their pc to install it?

Comment: If you only want to get installed on their device then you can use few free services like https://www.diawi.com/  Simply upload the app & send a link to your friends. Note that link will be active for the limited time & also check your app's data sensitivity.

Comment: OK, Ill probably do that :) Thanks