# Is there a way to distribute an internal app using only the Ad Hoc distribution profile?

Tags: ios, xcode

Recently i got myself into tring to sign and distribute an internal ios application using a developer subscription (Ad Hoc).

So my final solution after researching was creating a page which has a link used to install the profile and a link to trigger the .ipa installation.

Is there a way to distribute the .ipa file only using the Ad Hoc distribution profile ?

Comment: You need Apple Enterprise Developer account to distribute like that I guess.

Comment: @BadhanGanesh Are you 100% sure? Do you have a valid source or some kind of documentation ?

Comment: This post might help: https://medium.com/wso2-iot/how-to-export-in-house-developed-ios-app-as-an-enterprise-application-dc087bdd64c3

Comment: this may be help you  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8136307/enterprise-in-house-app-distribution

Comment: Enterprise distribution requires no registering of devices. Just an https link is suffice. Normal Ad-Hoc needs registering of all the required devices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your account is apple developer account, you can create .ipa with AdHoc provisioning profile. And you can use www.diawi.com to distribute it to internal testers. 
But you need to first register all the device's UDID to the development profile. You can add max 100 devices.

You can also use apple enterprise account, if you are developing it for internal use only. In that case you can directly give app to users without registering UDID of the devices.

Comment: First of all thanks, (talking about enterprise account) do they have to enter or enroll to a team or something like that, so that they will only have access to that download or via some kind of link?

Comment: You can use 'https://www.diawi.com/', upload your .ipa here and it will give you link, which you can share with all people in your organisation. 
Also just FYI enterprise account charges are 299$ per year whereas developer account needs just 99$ per year.

Comment: under the enterprise account charges are there extra charges for assigning provisioning privileges to your developers ?

Comment: It's one time payment, while getting an enterprise account, yearly 299$.