# ad-hoc AIR app installation, without UDIDs

Tags: ios, air, wireless, ipa, adhoc

I am currently building an AIR app for iOS, targeting iPad, with Flash CS5.5. I realize Flash gives me the option to build and deploy the app as an ad-hoc deployment which is fine. But what I'd really like to do is replicate the process here:

[How to distribute ios application wirelessly without managing UDIDs and recompilation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5546581/how-to-distribute-ios-application-wirelessly-without-managing-udids-and-recompil)

Where I can point users to a web link that lets them install the app on their device, regardless of whether their UDID is in the provision.

Flash generates the ipa file fine, but when I upload the ipa and provision file to my ftp server, and try to install on my iPad, an alert box come up saying "Can't connect"

The key piece of the html install looks like this:

`<a href="itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=http://www.example.com/ipadapp/myApp/myApp.plist"><img src="icon_57.png" alt="" width="59" /></a>`

It seems the missing piece is the .plist file, but I don't know how to generate that from Flash/AIR.

I have a normal Apple developer account (not enterprise).. not sure if that factors into things. Thanks!

Comment: I'm starting to think I need an enterprise account to do this. Would love it if someone could confirm.

Comment: I can confirm this, you need an enterprise account to distribute in-house apps.

Comment: Doesn't really need enterprise account? (As you accept the answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of a .plist file for OTA distribution.
You do **not** need enterprise account for this

http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1829415&seqNum=16