# iOS7.1 - install .ipa with wireless AdHoc distribution and Entreprise account

Tags: xcode5, enterprise, ios7.1, software-distribution, ad-hoc-distribution

I have some questions about the installation of .ipa file with wireless AdHoc distribution and Enterprise account to be completely clear in my mind (we use XCode 5.1, iOS 7.1)

1. I read ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8236750/ad-hoc-air-app-installation-without-udids)) that, for adhoc distribution, we don't need an Entreprise account, is that true ? Because I tested the method described in the link but it didn't work.
2. Do we need an Entitlement file anymore ?
3. Is the mobileprovision file already included in the .ipa file generated by XCode 5.1 ? (if we do Product -> Archive -> Distribute -> Save for Enterprise or Ad Hoc deployment and so on ...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. AFAIK without enterprise account you can't do Adhoc distribution and the link you have shared is old one with iOS 5 example.
2. I guess i didn't get your question completely. In the end Entitlement file is just a `plist` file and you can add as much as you wish.
3. Yes mobile provision file will be included while building the `.ipa`

---

You can verify the third point with the following steps

1. Rename the extension from `*.ipa` file to `*.zip`.
2. Unarchive the zip file.
3. The folder contains a `*.app` file. Right click and open the package contents.You'll find an embedded.mobileprovision file.