# iOS Enterprise app distribution helper that doesn't require UDIDs setting up

Tags: ios, testflight

I have an Enterprise Program account in the Apple developer program. Currently I'm using TestFlight to distribute an app, which still seems to require that the distribution profile contain each tester's UDID (even for Enterprise apps).

Are there any alternatives to TestFlight (aside from basic DIY placing of the files on a webserver somewhere) that will let me

a) distribute my Enterprise app without the UDID hassle,

b) still allow some control over who installs the app,

c) offer some features similar to TestFlight?

I've googled for this but it's tricky to formulate a search for these criteria.

**Update**

The Enterprise program forbids distribution of the app to anyone outside your own organisation. I'm curious if this would apply to a service such as TestFlight; this might exaplin the lack of such 3rd party services that can distribute your enterprise apps in the true enterprise fashion (as opposed to treating them as Ad Hoc where UDIDs are required still).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TestFlight now supports uploading of Enterprise builds (without any UDIDs associated). Maybe it always did! I was convinced for a long time it wasn't permitted, but I can't find anything to substantiate that now.

Answer (score -1):

The "hassle" is caused not by TestFlight, but by Apple - the device will reject the application if it's not signed for it, so there is no service working without UDIDs.

ps. You could always jailbreak your devices and disable signature checking, but I'm not aware of any service which take advantage of this.

Comment: Enterprise signed apps are not required to contain the UDID of each device they run on! See, for example, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5546581/how-to-distribute-ios-application-wirelessly-without-managing-udids-and-recompil