# Unable to download application on some idevices

Tags: ios, ios5, ios4

I had created a in-house-apps and give a link to download & install,but when click the link to download & install for some idevices it will popup "unable to download application" message.For those devices cannot be install is jailbroken devices.I am not sure is that affect  by jailbroken onot.By the way i follow the step to troubleshooting from IOS Developer Library.

```
 Troubleshooting wireless app distribution
 If wireless app distribution fails with an “unable to download” message, 
 check the following:

 -Make sure the app is signed correctly. Test it by installing it on a device 
 using iPhone Configuration Utility.

 -Make sure the URL to the .ipa file (in the manifest file) is correct and 
 the file is accessible to web users.

  -Make sure that the link to the manifest file is correct and 
   that the manifest file is accessible to web users.
```

But all the way i try it work fine.But still cannot install by link i created?How to solve that?

My English not very well ,Please forgive and Understand

Answer (score 0):

These are apps being signed with an Enterprise account?

Comment: No,Did i have to register a enterprise account?
But Some of my i device can be install

Comment: Yeah, but you are using a developer account with a few registered devices against it. Those devices will be able to install your developer/ad hoc builds, but they will expire in 6 months time. You need an enterprise licence to do this properly. https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5546581/how-to-distribute-ios-application-wirelessly-without-managing-udids-and-recompil/5558057#5558057
I agree what u said may be some different for those apple account type but
the link said can test by installing mobileprovision file,
and also the other devices that cannot be install already register under my provision file,still cannot install it?

Comment: Did you add the provision to the other devices? Even if these devices were included in the provisioning profile, if the provision is not installed in these devices, the app will not install.

Comment: yoninja:yeah i did,i install the provision follow the step from the link i provide.

Comment: If you installed the provisioning profile to all the devices then all the devices can install the app. Please double check the provisioning profile if it has all the UDIDs and check all the devices if they have  the provisioning profile installed in them.