# What is the easiest way to distribute an iPhone app im my organzation only.

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I want to distribute an iPhone app in my organization, (device ID free) and possibly over the air, is there any way to distribute app without asking device ID's over the air in an organization.

Comment: Have a look at TestFlight. It's great. A little fiddly to set up but it's a great solution once you're away. https://testflightapp.com

Comment: Please use search and google. This question has been answered here quite some times. One example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5546581/how-to-distribute-ios-application-wirelessly-without-managing-udids-and-recompil

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want it for your organisation only:

UDID Needed, Enterprise program
Over the air installation: MDM (Mobile Device Management)
https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/

IF you want it for everyone:

Use the app store, they can install it without you need the device id (UDID)
https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/

**EDIT**

Okay, i looked into it again. You were true. You can create in xcode:
Product > Archive > Distribute > For in house- enterprise apps. Than you can send it over MDM or with: iPhone configuration utility, xcode & iTunes 8.

Good luck with your organisation app

Comment: UDID are not needed of app singed with inHouse distribution profiles (aka Enterprise program).

Comment: You need to assign an iOs device in your developers program. For this you need the udid. i am using this program, and i need to assign the devices with UDID, thats what the organizer in xcode does.

Comment: You are wrong.  Enterprise does not care about UDID.  Only Ad-Hoc does.

Comment: Okay, i thought it was. But here in the provisioning profile, there is an UDID needed: http://udn.epicgames.com/Three/rsrc/Three/AppleiOSProvisioningPortal/ios_provision_devices_home.png

Comment: Okay, made the edit. Looked into it again