# Can I send a build of my app to people without them having a registered device?

Tags: iphone, ios, installation

I read an article about an app which allowed users to enter a URL and download an app, without being a registered developer device:

http://www.iphonehacks.com/2013/07/how-to-install-gba-emulator-for-ios-without-jailbreaking.html

I was wondering how this was possible, as it'd be useful for my own purposes?

Answer (score 0):

The ["iOS Developer Enterprise Program"](https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/)
allows you to distribute iOS apps to devices without having them registered, but it is allowed
**only** for the distribution of in-house apps within a company.

(The article http://www.iphonehacks.com/2013/07/apple-revokes-gba4ios-signing-certificate.html
tells that the iOS Enterprise Program was abused to freely distribute apps and as a consequence, Apple revoked the certificate.)

Answer (score 0):

They used an enterprise distribution certificate for signing their app.
https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/

The certificate may be used for distribution inside a company. Please refer to this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5546581/how-to-distribute-ios-application-wirelessly-without-managing-udids-and-recompil) for more details on how to manage your in-house apps distribution.