# Installing IOS apps over Air Watch without UDID?

Tags: ios, xcode, ad-hoc-distribution

I've just started using Air Watch to distribute in-house ios applications. Unless I build the Ad-Hoc profile with the UDID explicitly listed in the profile, my app will not install on any enrolled devices. Anyone know if there is another way to get these applications installed over AW without managing a list of thousands of UDIDs? Indeed there are [ways of using a plist file and distributing from a webserver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5546581/how-to-distribute-ios-application-wirelessly-without-managing-udids-and-recompil), but we need a way to remotely wipe the installed applications when a device, or employee, goes MIA.

Comment: Are you able to host the app file (the manifest and .ipa file?) on a local server?

Comment: We could remotely host as in the link above, however if I am not mistaken, that does not lend itself to removing the application or data if the device is released from service.

Comment: well, in regards to removing the data, Apple already has an app for that: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/find-my-iphone/id376101648. I thought you wanted to be able to install apps remotely.

Answer (score 0):

Unless the device is jailbroken, maintenance of the UDID list is required by Apple for anything outside of the App Store. This is enforced by iOS itself. It's obnoxious, but it's the way it is.

If you need more than 100 devices for in-house deployment, be sure to look at Apple's [Enterprise Developer Program](https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/gettingstarted/). The program supports many more features than the regular developer program's ad-hoc system. To enroll, visit https://developer.apple.com/programs/start/enterprise/

Comment: Indeed. That sure seems to be the case. Isn't there a limit of 100 UDIDs with Ad-Hoc?

Comment: I think so. Though there is also in-house app distribution for enterprises that allows for many more devices. That may, or may not work for your purposes. See https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/gettingstarted/

Comment: Aha.. Ok, so following that link.. do I need both an "In House" certificate as well as "In House" (instead of Ad Hoc) provisioning profile?  My "In House" cert option is currently greyed out and I'm not sure why (I'm relatively new to ios development).

Comment: You need to sign up and pay for the Enterprise developer program. Te normal developer program does not have this option. To enroll, visit https://developer.apple.com/programs/start/enterprise/

Comment: Hmm.. I do indeed have the $299 Enterprise developer program.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43366/discussion-between-wufoo-and-bergquester)