# Not able to install .ipa with enterprise distribution on Ipod Touch IOS 8.0

Tags: touch, ipod, ipa

I developed an IOS App on Xcode 6.0.1. The university I work for wrapped the App with an enterprise distribution license and sent me the .ipa file. I dragged the .ipa file onto iTunes and synced the Ipod Touch with it. I tries to install the App. I says installing on iTunes and a black logo appears on the Ipod Touch with the message Installing. This goes on for hours without installation.

I tried to install the App with HockeyApp. It tries to install the App. I can see the Logo of my App on the screen, after a while I get the message,

Unable to Download App "App" could not be able to installed at this time.

Even our IT service department is not able to give any suggestions. Is there any work around?

Thanks
Anu

Comment: Did you check whether your device has been added to the Device List?

Comment: I checked, my device is not added. The team who wrapped my App with the license claim, they were able to run it on an Iphone and it is not necessary to add the device UUID. Is this true?

Comment: Cheek this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5546581/how-to-distribute-ios-application-wirelessly-without-managing-udids-and-recompil