# Distribute enterprise IPA using local server

Tags: ios, build, share, enterprise, ipa

I am trying to share my enterprise build via my server. First of all, I want to test process on my local server. The problem is that app was not installed on my device.

I tried to install app in 2 ways:

**1. Open direct link for .ipa file. Safari just displays file picture, name and size**

[image]

**2. Open link for distribution .plist file. I was guided by this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5546581/how-to-distribute-ios-application-wirelessly-without-managing-udids-and-recompil). Safari says app cannot be installed**

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem seems to be that the server you deployed your .ipa/.plist files to doesn't have a valid https certificate. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20276907/enterprise-app-deployment-doesnt-work-on-ios-7-1) for solutions and an easy workaround using Dropbox.

Answer (score 0):

Use below link it will helps you and solved your problem

http://gknops.github.io/adHocGenerate/

Comment: this link was used in my 2nd attempt, as I described, Safari says app cannot be installed

Comment: se this link now hope it helps