# Enterprise distribution apps on iOS, possible to drag and drop the ipa into iTunes?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, itunes, enterprise-distribution

Just curious, if I compile an app configured for enterprise distribution can I simply drag and drop the IPA built into iTunes then install it on an iDevice?

Comment: I don't see why not, give it a try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can also set it up for wireless distribution.  This is assumping you know how to build and code sign it with the correct provisioning profile.  See this question for info on how to distribute it wirelessly.

[iOS 4: wireless app distribution for in-house applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3098290/ios-4-wireless-app-distribution-for-in-house-applications)

Answer (score 2):

Definitely possible. That used to be the regular way, until OTA came along in iOS 4.0. The app can be mailed to the user, or can be downloaded by her from intranet portal, which is then copied to iTunes and synced like an app store app.